# If I pass electricity through heating coils will it make heat?

Tags: heat, coil

This may sound like a silly question. But if I strip some wires  added the connectors and connect them to a heating coil will it heat the coil up? What else would I need to produce heat?

Comment: No it won't heats up until the wires are connected to the suitable power source.

Comment: So let's say I connected the wires to a car battery or something. Then would it heat up?

Comment: Depends upon Heater's Voltage and Wattage ratings. A small  torch-bulb's filament is also a heating-coil. It heats-up significantly in 1.5 volt

Comment: Torch bulb using filaments met extinction, just like dinasours... Pls give other example.

Comment: @ soosai steven I mentioned it  just-as **example** .  If I could recall modern- such example, I'll add, btw if you know, you obviously could mention that.

Comment: I used words "light bulb heats up" to mean "heats-up enough a tiny-piece of wire enough to give out incandescent light"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, connecting a heating coil (a section of high heat output wire like nichrome or similar) to regular copper wires and a power supply properly will create heat. It will be proportional to how much power in Volts * Amps you put through it. A significantly weak supply will produce heat in wasted power, though it may be too small to register. A significantly strong supply may produce enough heat to melt the coil or wires.

It highly depends on the coil and supply used.

Comment: @LostPecti: Passerby won't mind me saying this but you should wait a day or two before accepting an answer. Accepting dissuades others from posting and you may miss a better one. You can un-accept and re-accept later.

Comment: Dont mind at all :)

Comment: Since the answer is accepted, let me just add this: it is important for the coil resistance to be significantly larger than the source resistance. Something will heat up either way, but maybe not what you want--and a battery or a power supply are not designed to function as heaters.

Answer (score 1):

**Indeed inside a simple heater there is nothing except a heating-coil**.
(resistance wire made of **Nichrome** (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nichrome), an alloy with high-melting-point and low reaction with air).

**If you use a small battery, say 1.5 Volts;  coil will heated, but in negligible amount. If you give mains-supply(higher-voltage, causing higher-current), coil will rapidly heat-up.**

Search "Joule-heating" (Resistive heating) in wikipedia.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule_heating.

Whatever you use DC source, or AC-source; the situation would be similar.

However, for further information;  a More-conductive wire (**Less "resistance"** ) produce **heat more**-rapidly (so soon-attain a high-temperature), and rated as more-Wattage power-dissipation al a voltage limit. In same-way; a Less-conductive wire (**more Resistance**) will give you **lesser heat**, and rated as a lesser-wattage within a range of supplied voltage.

H= (const.) * (I^2) * R * t     .  .  .  .  .   ( **t** is time here)

=> H= (const.) * (I^2) * (V/I) * t

**=> H= (const.) * I * V * t.**

**( => H varies directly in-proportion with applied V , when you are using a single piece of heating-wire)**.

The impact of varying R could be understood only when 2 or more heater will-be kept in series, so the same current will flow through all these resistors. Then the heater with highest resistance ("tightest"-one) produce more heat in comparison to the other heaters.

Also, there is not significant effect of coil-shape in "production" of heat (so far I know); it just cause LOWERING the open surface area, so the heat-energy cannot dissipate-out fast; causing more-temperature (degree C) at the end of equilibrium. If **you could uncoil** the wire completely, then also the wire will emit heat-energy... but since the heat-energy lost quickly, it might be end-up being steady at a lesser temperature.