PCB stackup that requires carrying 100 A at 12 V DC
I'm working on a PCB design that requires carrying 100 A at 12 V DC and several signals with frequencies below 3 MHz, for which fan-out I need two SIG layers. I'm aiming for a 3 mm thick, 30 × 30 mm, multilayer PCB with four to eight layers.
I understand that internal layers dissipate heat less efficiently than external ones. Based on this, I've come up with the following stackup option focusing on thermal management:

PWR1 (100 μm Cu) - 12 V DC
GND1 (90 μm Cu)
SIG (17 μm Cu)
SIG (17 μm Cu)
GND1 (90 μm Cu)
PWR1 (100 μm Cu) - 12 V DC

I'm considering adding dedicated signal reference planes to improve impedance control and reduce crosstalk. This would also allow for thinner signal conductors.
Here's an alternative stackup with signal reference planes:

PWR1 (100 μm Cu) - 12 V DC
GND1 (90 μm Cu)
GND1 (SIG_REF) (17 μm Cu)
SIG (17 μm Cu)
SIG (17 μm Cu)
GND1 (SIG_REF) (17 μm Cu)
GND1 (90 μm Cu)
PWR1 (100 μm Cu) - 12 V DC

I would appreciate your expertise in helping me select the optimal stackup for my application.

What would your component placement look like? How much board area is dedicated to the 100A connectors and related components? I suspect a strict stackup question isn't quite as useful as you have imagined...

How wide can you make the traces? Cross sectional area is important.

How many 100A traces do you need?

note that the power you transport on these high-amperage traces actually flows as the electric field between them – and ground, hopefully. Corollary, you need to make your ground as beefy as them – and internal traces have a harder time getting rid of heat than external traces.

Even if you used the whole layer for power trace, you would still have 0.17W dissipation pr power layer.

Relevant question: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/59735/creating-a-high-current-bus-on-a-pcb

Either I'd look for external conductors, or at the very least discuss with my PCB manufacturer about the thickest possible outer layer copper that they can produce reliably, and then see if the clearance rules for that copper thickness is compatible with the components you want to use.

Relevant question 2: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/18874/how-to-carry-high-current-on-pcb

Why close? These type of q/a or more helpful than many questions left open.
